# Let $f$ be a continuous Lipschitz function, then exists unique solution for $x'=f(t,x)$ with $x(t_0)=x_0$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be continuous and Lipschitz. How do I prove that there exists unique solution of the IVP $x'=f(t,x),\quad x(t_0)=x_0$

for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$.

I tried to use the Banach fixed-point theorem, but I think that $M=C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^n)$ is not a complete metric space whit the supremum norm. The reason I tried this is to define $T:M\rightarrow M$ as $T(z)(t)=x_0+\int_{t_0}^{t} f(s,z(s))\,ds$ and prove that there exist a fixed point using the following inequality

$$\|T(x)(t)-T(y)(t)\|\leq \frac{L^n \lvert t-t_0\rvert^n}{n!}d(x,y),$$

where $L$ is the Lipschitz constant for $f$ and $d(x,y)=\sup\limits_{t\in \mathbb{R}}\|x(t)-y(t)\|$.

Can somebody give me a hand?

Comment: You can restrict your intervalle of parameters from $\mathbb{R}$ to a segment $[a,b]$. $C([a,b],\mathbb{R}^n)$ is complete for the supremum norm. Then you construct a solution on $\mathbb{R}$ from the local solutions

Comment: @AlexL Your comment solve the two problems I had, since I don't need the inequality depending on $t$. But how do I construct the global solution given the local solution? I am so sorry is this questions seems to be stupid to you, but I am new in the ODE course and I am having problems to understand it well.

Comment: Take a solution $f_n$ on $I_n=[-n+t_0,n+t_0]$ for $n >0$ an interger. Then by unicity of solutions on $I_n$, then $f_{n+1 | I_n}=f_n$ so you can define a solution on $\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=f_n(x)$ for $x \in I_n$. This is a solution and it is uniquely defined on each $I_n$, so it is the only solution on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @AlexL My sincerest and most appreciated respects to you. I have understood your explanation clearly and greatly appreciate your help. Have a great rest of the day.